# Format XML with Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and I'm making a program that formats XML files. This program, however, is taking the namespace of some tags and replicating it in the others. I want to stop this behavior.

```
func main() {
    openedFile, _ := os.Open("originalFile.xml")

    xmlDecoder := xml.NewDecoder(openedFile)

    createdFile, _ := os.Create("result.xml")

    xmlEncoder := xml.NewEncoder(createdFile)

    xmlEncoder.Indent("", "  ")

    for {
        tokenXml, err := xmlDecoder.Token()

        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }

        xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(tokenXml)
    }

    if err := xmlEncoder.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

The original XML file looks like this:

`<TEST1 xmlns="text"><TEST2><TEST3></TEST3></TEST2></TEST1>`

When i run the code, i get the following result:

```
<TEST1 xmlns="text" xmlns="text">
  <TEST2 xmlns="text">
    <TEST3 xmlns="text"></TEST3>
  </TEST2>
</TEST1>
```

Note that the namespaces have been replicated.

If possible, I would also like to have the program remove the following line:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

I'm newer in Golang, so i'm learning.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: Instead of `Decoder.Token`, try using `Decoder.RawToken`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Burak Serdar mentioned, you can use [RawToken()](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder.RawToken) instead of `Token()` to avoid duplicating the attributes. Regarding the `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, you can add a switch check of the token type to skip encoding the token to the new file if the token is of type [xml.ProcInst](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#ProcInst)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    openedFile, _ := os.Open("originalFile.xml")

    xmlDecoder := xml.NewDecoder(openedFile)

    createdFile, _ := os.Create("result.xml")

    xmlEncoder := xml.NewEncoder(createdFile)

    xmlEncoder.Indent("", "  ")

    for {
        tokenXml, err := xmlDecoder.RawToken()

        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }

        switch tokenXml.(type) {
        case xml.ProcInst:
            continue
        }
        
        xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(tokenXml)
    }

    if err := xmlEncoder.Flush(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`xmlDecoder.RawToken()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder.RawToken) instead of [`xmlDecoder.Token()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder.Token) :

```
tokenXml, err := xmlDecoder.RawToken()
if err != nil {
    ...
}
xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(tokenXml)
```

(playground: https://go.dev/play/p/AzfswZf70UI)

---

RawToken() will not try to compute namespace information based on previous context.

Answer (score 0):

You can add t.Name.Space  to empty string to remove unwanted namespaces. tHe below code also adds the xml version tag to the output.

```
    func main() {
        openedFile, _ := os.Open("originalFile.xml")
        xmlDecoder := xml.NewDecoder(openedFile)
        createdFile, _ := os.Create("result.xml")
        defer createdFile.Close()
    
        xmlEncoder := xml.NewEncoder(createdFile)
        xmlEncoder.Indent("", "  ")
        defer xmlEncoder.Flush()
    
        createdFile.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
    
        // Tracking if root element has been written or not
        var rootWritten bool
    
        for {
            token, err := xmlDecoder.Token()
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                break
            }
    
            switch t := token.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                // If root element, I remove namespace
                if !rootWritten {
                    t.Name.Space = ""
                    rootWritten = true
                } else {
                    // Remove namespace for elements without explicit namespace declaration
                    t.Name.Space = ""
                    for i := range t.Attr {
                        if t.Attr[i].Name.Space == "xmlns" && t.Attr[i].Name.Local == "" {
                            t.Attr = append(t.Attr[:i], t.Attr[i+1:]...)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                // Encode the start element
                xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(t)
    
            case xml.EndElement:
                xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(t)
    
            default:
                xmlEncoder.EncodeToken(t)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST1 xmlns="text">
  <TEST2>
    <TEST3>
```